# Gated checkins missing from completed builds

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, gated-checkin

When reviewing the Build History via the browser (servername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/MyProj/_Build), I find that there are numerous missing entries for builds which were triggered via gated checkins. When I filter on only that build definition, I find a handful of entries, compared to hundreds of code checkins.

All developers are required to use the gated builds, and all checkins show the telltale signs of success (***NO_CI***)

Using the API, I find the identical results, which is the root problem...

What would cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

check the Retention Policy set on your build definition.  By default only the most recent 10 builds will be kept.

Comment: I am referring to the build status, not the actual builds themselves. Using the API, I can go back over a year, and get build statuses, which obviously are > 10.